VS code keep changed line indication for stage files
i am facing the following issue in VS code + git,
when chaging a line :

i see the change indication
now when i add this file to "stage mode" in git ( git add < file name> ), i am loosing this indication

how can i keep this indication for stage files as well ... i tried to ignore this behavior
but it keeps bugging me, and now i understand that this is critical for me.
so only when i commit - i want this indication to be removed.
Thanks !
P.S i have searched all similar Q's and did not found some thing similar - hope this is not a DUP
